# I want to execute test.sh by "mvn atf:itest" by given pom

Tags: maven, plugins

I am not familiar with maven. However, I know it is a popular build framework. So I create a below pom.xml and wish to execute testing with command line "mvn atf:itest":

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>john.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>Maventest</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Maventest</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <build>
  <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>atf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itest</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>ITest</id>
        <phase>Testing</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>itest</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <executable>${basedir}/scripts/test.py</executable>
          <arguments>
            <argument>-s</argument>
          </arguments>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

But the output show below error message:
[image: # mvn atf:itest:1.2]

Any suggestion?

Comment: I just refer to "https://sanchitbahal.wordpress.com/2011/09/19/maven-exec-plugin-vs-maven-antrun-plugin-for-running-command-line-tool/". However, it doesn't provide complete pom.xml and the command to execute the command in plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Among other things, Maven works with plugins.
This statement:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>atf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itest</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
```

...tells Maven that you want to include in your project a particular plugin.

However, I can't find such plugin in [Maven Central Repository](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Catf). If you have this plugin placed in a repository of yours, you should tell Maven where to find it, via `repositories` section.

Comment: So if I only want maven to execute the external py file, is there a proper way to do it? Said "mvn itest"?

Comment: In order to do that, you'd need a plugin that knows how to run python files. I don't know where you dug out atf/itest from; unless this artifact is in a local repository of yours somewhere, it can't work, because Maven doesn't know who that plugin is.
To answer your question: if you want to execute python scripts then you need to dig out a plugin that suits your needs (there are probably several), and properly configure it in your project; I haven't ran python before so I don't really know what to recommend.

Comment: Hi Andrei, Got it. Many thanks! Let me dig into how-to.